# In typescript, How to use a generic to constraint and describe return value type of function？

Tags: typescript, function, generics

Look the code ,I think tom is type of BB extends AA, So it should be work

Code Error:
TS2322: Type 'BB' is not assignable to type 'T'

```js
interface AA {
    name: string
}
interface BB extends AA{
    age: number
}
const tom: BB = {
    name: 'tom',
    age: 20
}
function something<T extends AA>(): T {
    return tom
}
```

How can I use like

```
something<BB>()
```

to get a value which extends AA 
; Or

```
something<CC>()
```

which CC extends AA

Comment: What are you trying to do? The function is named "identity" which means its output is the same as its input... but it takes *no* input. The type signature `f<T extends AA>(): T` says "given no input whatsoever, produce a value of a type subtype `T` of `AA` specified by the *caller* of the function." That's not possible; the type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) upon compilation, so both `f<BB>()` and `f<CC>()` will be emitted to JS as `f()`... how could such a function be implemented? A [mcve] of your use case would be very useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Your identify function should look like this:

```
interface AA {
    name: string
}
interface BB extends AA{
    age: number
}
const tom: BB = {
    name: 'tom',
    age: 20
}
function identity<T extends AA>(arg: T) {
    return arg
}

identity(tom)
```

The problem with you current implementation is that you are using a specific kind of type `T`.